# Почему правила CSS не применяются к тегам HTML?

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь сделать заказ обратного звонка на [сайте](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/), но почему-то не работают правила CSS.
Вот Html код, который я добавил в шапку сайта:

```
<div class="callback">
    <img width="65" height="56"  src="http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/callback.png" alt="Заказать обратный звонок">
        <a href="#" title="Заказать обратный звонок">Заказать обратный звонок</a>
    </img>
</div>
```

Вот CSS код:

```
div.callback{
    display: none !important;
}

div.callback a{
    font-family: HeliosBlack;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Кэширование отключено. Почему правила CSS не применяются к тегам HTML?

Comment: display: none; - это значит что блок скрыт

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/dpkm4x93/

display: none; block скрыт

для tag **img** - Закрывающий тег не требуется

как вариант http://jsfiddle.net/v0odobyw/

Comment: Это понятно, мне нужно понять, в чем проблема именно на этом сайте!?

Comment: @eprivalov1, я не вижу div-контейнера с классом `.callback` на Вашем сайте.

Answer (score 2):

[[@eprivalov1](/users/6953/eprivalov1)](/users/6953/eprivalov1)

- Тег [`<img>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/img) не должен иметь закрывающего тега
- Дополнительное уточнение `div.` избыточно
- Использование `!important` крайне нежелательно

Answer (score 1):

Вот так должно заработать:

```
[html]

<div class="callback">

    <a href="#" title="Заказать обратный звонок">
         <img width="65" height="56"  src="http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/callback.png" alt="Заказать обратный звонок" />
    </a>

</div>

[/html]

Вот CSS код:

[css]

.callback {
    display: none;
}

.callback a {
    font-family: HeliosBlack;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}

[/css]
```